# keyboard not working in Ubuntu 18.04Lts

Tags: gnome, kernel, keyboard, 18.04

Actually a few days back I switched from windows 10 to Ubuntu 18.04 LTS version. Everything was fine till today suddenly due to some power failure (loose battery) my laptop went off while working on it. 
After starting laptop I was able to put the password in the login screen however after that keyboard didn't work. Things I tried:

1. Reinstalled xserver-xorg-input-all
2. Checked for slow keys in universal access> typing. It is off.
3. The keyboard is working fine in the grub menu.
4. My caps lock key has led indicator so before putting password if the light is on then it will remain on and vice versa. Which means the keyboard is freezing after login.
5. As Ubuntu 18.04 comes with Gnome3, I tried replacing with unity but after that situation gets even worse. The keyboard was not even working on the login screen.
6. Tried repairing all broken packages in Ubuntu generic recovery option.
7. My Ubuntu is fully updated.
8. No additional driver is needed to install.

Answer (score 2):

Don't know the exact reason. But i tried uninstalling Gnome3 and replacing this by unity8, as mentioned earlier. After that with the help of on screen keyboard i logged in tty screen. There i again uninstalled unity and installed gd3. Also made it default. Things worked out, for me.